# Fetching data using a async function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have been trying to create a table from an array of objects. I'm able to console the data inside the async function. But I couldn't console it outside.

My code :

```
useEffect(() => {
  listingCampaignsModels()
}, []);


async function listingCampaignsModels() {
    const apiData = await DataStore.query(Campaign);
    console.log(apiData);
    console.log(typeof(apiData));
    return apiData;
  };
```

When I tried to console `apiData` outside, it returns `apiData is not defined` error.

The data looks like this :

```
[Model, Model, Model, Model, Model, Model]
```

Each `Model` looks like :

```
-> 1: Model {id: 'c40d6b22-840f-467a-909c-7b2b19960ffb', campaignOwner: 'eumagnas', campaignName: "mollitlab", startDate: "2022/08/15", endDate: "2022/10/25", expectedRevenue: 25, budgetedCost: 27, actualCost: 28}
```

I want loop through all the Models and create a table as :

| Campaign Owner | Campaign Name | Start Date | End Date | Expected Revenue | Budgeted Cost | Actual Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| eumagnas | mollitlab | 2022/08/15 | 2022/10/25 | 25 | 27 | 28 |

Comment: You need to set the data into some state, eg if you have `const [ campaigns, setCampaigns ] = useState([])`, then you would use `listingCampaignsModels().then(setCampaigns)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `useState()` hook to save the data as campaign state.

```
const [campaigns, setCampaigns] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  listingCampaignsModels()
}, []);


async function listingCampaignsModels() {
    const apiData = await DataStore.query(Campaign);
    console.log(apiData);
    setCampaigns(apiData);
  };
```